# Generic business rule engine

Tags: c#, generics, interface, business-logic, rule

I need to code a business rule engine using C#. The basic thing is that it is a rule engine for a store. Where people can buy all sorts of things.

> Examples of rules:
>   * If they buy a item, I'll send a shipping slip.
>   * If they buy a cd, I'll create a royalty slip for the royalty payments.
>   * If they buy a membership, I'll activate it
>   * If they buy a video called "Karate", i'll add a free "first aid" video on top.

I must make it very scalable as many (100+ rules) could be in effect at one time.

My first thought was to make the following:

> A table, with a product type (e.g. book), and an action (would be the class name)
>
> All the action classes would then Impliment an interface IAction with a mandatory "Run()" method.
>
> And you could then create rules implementing this interface.
>
> As a product was bought, the table would then have 1 or more rows of actions that needed to be started. And then a factory class would instantiate this rule, and activate the "run" method.

Basically the code needs to be scalable, and handle the high complexity and a possible high rate of change with minimum maintenance. I feel there would be a smarter method than the one above.

So my question is: What would be a clever way of solving this?

Comment: So, what's your question? Also please make it very specific, if you leave your story like it is it will be too broad.

Comment: My question is, is my way of solving this business rule engine the way to do it, or is there a way smarter way.
Like if I wanted to implement a rule engine with IF something THEN something - People would probably say Expression Trees. But this is something else. This is 1 or more actions based on a certain type of order.

I was wondering if this is doable in any clever way.